# How to template a data structure within a class all in-line (same .h file)

Tags: c++, class, templates, struct

Ive been assigned to turn my linked list class into a template and I'm running into some confusion. I need to submit it as as a single `.h` file.

When I try to build i'm getting errors on every mention of `LLnode`, `fwdPtr`, and `theData`. That is every element of the structure so Ive done something very wrong there. Also, the `struct` definition itself is marked with a `syntax error`

```
template <class V>
class LL
{
    private:
        LLnode * header;
        struct <V> LLnode;
        {
            LLnode * fwdPtr; // has a pointer member
            V theData; // the data within the node
        };

    public:
        LL()
            {
                header = nullptr;
            }
        void push_front(string data)  
        {
            LLnode * new_node;
            new_node = new LLnode;                          
            new_node -> theData = data;                     

            if (header == nullptr)                      
            {                                               
                header = new_node;                    
                new_node -> fwdPtr = nullptr;
            }
            else                                            
            {
                LLnode * temp;                              
                temp = header;                          
                header = new_node;                      
                new_node -> fwdPtr = temp;                  
            }

            return;
        }
        .... more functions below ....
```

In the `main()`, upon which the function will be tested, a new linked list will be instantiated with `<string>` cast as the type. This is why I moved the `struct LLnode` inside the `private` member section of `class LL`. This is also why I am using `V` throughout the structure. Because that cast needs to reach down to the structure itself so when I dynamically allocate memory for nodes it will know to accept `string` data

I know I will need to change the function definitions to include `V` and use `V` throughout with some of the variables. But I don't understand where and why. Im confused on how template classes relate to pointer and programmer defined structures. I understand the simple examples of template classes/functions in my textbook but I am lost here.

Thanks in advance for any help!

EDIT: Here are the error messages im receiving (as requested)

```
../LL_template_class.h:23:3: error: unknown type name 'LLnode'
                LLnode * header;
                ^
../LL_template_class.h:24:3: error: declaration of anonymous struct must be a definition
                struct <V> LLnode;
                ^
../LL_template_class.h:24:3: warning: declaration does not declare anything [-Wmissing-declarations]
../LL_template_class.h:25:3: error: expected member name or ';' after declaration specifiers
                {
                ^
../LL_template_class.h:37:4: error: unknown type name 'LLnode'
                        LLnode * new_node;
                        ^
../LL_template_class.h:38:19: error: unknown type name 'LLnode'
                        new_node = new LLnode;
                                       ^
../LL_template_class.h:48:5: error: unknown type name 'LLnode'
                                LLnode * temp;
```

But like I said, I getting `can not resolve` errors on all mentions of my `struc LLnode` elements as well

Comment: Can you provide the information from the errors that you've received?

Comment: When you write `template <class V> class LL { ... };`, the compiler basically creates a "cookie cutter" template for `LL`. Then, when you instantiate `LL<int>`, it stamps out a new instance of the contents of `{ ... };` with the name `LL<int>` (similarly for other types). So your `struct <V> LLnode; { ... };` doesn't make sense, because if `LL` was _not_ a template, you'd just write `struct LLnode { ... };` and it would work as you expect. I find that it's often useful to start with a concrete type rather than a template (`LLInt` rather than `LL<T>`), then go back through and templatize.

Comment: To use Stackoverflow at its best - start by providing a [mcve]. The number of people wanting to help will increase a lot.

Comment: thank you very much @ Justin and @ Ted. I will try to condense  my questions a ot more in the future. It will probably help me figure out what the core of the problem is, as well get me more responses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems:

---

First, you are ending your declaration of `struct LLnode` too early (you have an extra semicolon). You have

```
struct LLnode;
{
...
};
```

You should have

```
struct LLnode
{
...
};
```

---

Secondly, you have the declaration `struct <V> LLnode`, when you should have the declaration `struct LLnode`. Having the `<V>` there makes no syntactical sense.

---

Also, I'm not sure if this is necessary, but you may need to move your declaration of `header` below your declaration of `LLnode`, since `header` is defined as an `LLnode`.